# Measurement Protocol HTTP Batch event POST instead of POST per event?

Tags: http, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I want to batch my requests to the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data

I'm developing in Unity 3D, but mainly I was curious if anyone had ideas so I can reduce the number of http requests from the client.

NOTE: I have no plans to use Googles Analytics SDK for Unity. Please do not suggest. I want to use the Measurement Protocol API.
Thanks,

NOTE: multipart/mixed might be a good solution, but I suspect the API needs to support it. Not sure if that is the case (at least not documented).

Seems like this should be a common problem though.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch)

You can batch multiple requests into a single post request.